# Notification buttons not showing

Tags: android, button, notifications

following [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html) guide and other discussions online I've made this pice of code that should show with the .addAction method the buttons in my notification:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void generateNotificationSong()
    {
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            builder.setContentTitle(songsList.get(currentSongIndex).getTitle());
            builder.setContentText("Next: " + songsList.get(getNextSong()).getTitle());
            builder.setOngoing(true); //E' in corso
            builder.setAutoCancel(true);


            //intent con activity che devo aprire (la corrente)
            Intent thisintent = getIntent();
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, thisintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


            //Aggiungo i bottoni alla notifica se android è > 4.1
            if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
            {
                Log.v("A", "CIAO");
                Intent prevIntent = new Intent();
                prevIntent.setAction("prec");
                PendingIntent pendingPrev = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 123, prevIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                Intent nextIntent = new Intent();
                nextIntent.setAction("next");
                PendingIntent pendingNext = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 123, nextIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                Intent pauseIntent = new Intent();
                pauseIntent.setAction("pause");
                PendingIntent pendingPause = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 123, pauseIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                builder.addAction(R.drawable.btn_previous, "Previous", pendingPrev);
                builder.addAction(R.drawable.btn_pause, "Pause", pendingNext);
                builder.addAction(R.drawable.btn_next, "Next", pendingPause);
            }

            //la setto alla notifica
            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            //infine la chiamo
            mNotify = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
                mNotify.notify(001, builder.build()); //funziona meglio
            else
                mNotify.notify(001, builder.getNotification()); //deprecated
        }
    }
```

What I get is my notification without the buttons I've added, I think I'm missing something but I've not found a solution yet

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Notification buttons not showing up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249871/android-notification-buttons-not-showing-up)

Answer (score 8):

Here is a possible cause. Android may hide the buttons when there are other notifications present, especially when your phone is being charged. Try tap your notification with two fingers and swipe down. You should be able to see your buttons.

Comment: Great hint! I didn't know about two fingers

Comment: I tried `.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)` and `setWhen(0)`, but still cannot see notification action button when **orientation is landscape**. Your answer save my life!!!!! many thanks ;-)

Comment: You sir, are as cunning as a fox.