# Is possible set Expanded Notification as default in Big Text Notifications?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-styles

I followed this [Sample Code](http://www.objc.io/issue-11/android-notifications.html)

In `Big Text Notifications` section, he said that need expand to see `Big text notification` form, as image im below :

[image]

I wonder that we can not `set Expanded Notification as default in Big Text Notifications?`

People who know it is can or not,

If can,

Please tell me how to do it,

Thanks,

Comment: You can change it by implementing custom notification, and by setting height as much you wish. I could write example if you want.

Comment: @DjDexter Please make the answer for people to know. If it really be useful, people and I will vote also.

Comment: Please read this amazing answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18603076/4120180

Answer (score 55):

The [documentation states](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#BigNotify):

> A notification's big view appears only when the notification is
>   expanded, which happens when the notification is at the top of the
>   notification drawer, or when the user expands the notification with a
>   gesture.

So my answer is no, you can't expand it by default.

There is however a trick to push the notification to the top of the list where it would be expanded. Simply set the Priority to [`Notification.PRIORITY_MAX`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#PRIORITY_MAX) and chances are that your app's notification will make it to the top.

Comment: Okay, thanks. It looks like Google only allow Gmail application can show this `Big Text Style` as default if there is only it was shown on Notification bar.

Comment: IMO Gmail doesn't expand its notifications at least not on the devices I just tested (only Nexus devices). BTW you can try to push your notifications to the top of the list so they get expanded. Not 100% reliable but better than nothing (I updated my answer accordingly).

Comment: "the top of the list where it would be expanded" - Yes, you're right. The devices supported from Android 4.1 can show `Big Text Style`. My Galaxy S3 can be showed it, not only Nexus devices.

Comment: The Automatic app seems to be pre-expanded when you've parked your car.

Comment: if P_MAX is set, then the notification will be displayed as a heads-up notification. As well, when I tried this, pushbullet, connected via usb, and mobile data limit exceeded notifications were still on top. Do you have a workaround as this doesnt seem to give the desired result.

Comment: It's no more on site - >>A notification's big view appears only when the notification is expanded, which happens when the notification is at the top of the notification drawer, or when the user expands the notification with a gesture.

Comment: I would warn against pushing your notifications to the top, just so that they are expanded.  Your priority level should be based on the UI guidelines - https://material.google.com/patterns/notifications.html#notifications-settings-priority.  Otherwise, you are very likely to upset your users.

Comment: My BigText overlaps small. This is not expand on click

Comment: Regarding Notification.PRIORITY_MAX, This constant was deprecated in API level 26.
use NotificationManager#IMPORTANCE_HIGH instead.

Answer (score 14):

```
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder()
... // The same notification properties as the others
.setStyle(new Notification.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(mBitmap))
.build();
```

You change

```
.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(th_alert))
```

along with the announcement

```
notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
```

Here is an example:

[image]You can set Code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReserveStatusActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
intent = new Intent(String.valueOf(PushActivity.class));
intent.putExtra("message", MESSAGE);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(PushActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
// PendingIntent pendingIntent =
stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigStyle = new     NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
// bigStyle.bigText((CharSequence) context);

notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle(th_title)
    .setContentText(th_alert)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
 // .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(th_alert)  ตัวเก่า
 // .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(th_title))
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(th_alert))
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .setNumber(++numMessages)
    .build();

notification.sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
notificationManager.notify(1000, notification);
```

Comment: My BigText overlaps small. This is not expand on click

Answer (score 1):

```
notificationBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Your Long Text here"))
```

simply `setStyle` of your notification builder.

Answer (score 0):

No need of doing any kind of modification in the any file for showing of multiple lines of Notification while using Push Notification V5, remove the field "style", from the object you are sending. Automatically the Multiple lines of notification will be seen. For more information, upvote the answer, ask your query. I will help you out.

For reference, [visit this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47525119/multiple-lines-of-text-message-for-push-notification-using-fcm-with-ionic-1/47525677#47525677)

Answer (score 0):

From this notification code you have got images, and big text or more.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_logo);
                mBuilder.setColor(Color.parseColor("#D74F4F"));
            } else {
                mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon);
            }

            mBuilder.setTicker(title).setWhen(when);
            mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            mBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(intent);
            mBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
            mBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), icon));
            mBuilder.setContentText(msg);
            mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
            if (Utils.validateString(banner_path)) {
                mBuilder.setStyle(notiStyle);
            } else {
                mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg));
            }

            Notification noti = mBuilder.build();
            notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

Comment: What's the part of "notiStyle" ? What is validateString ?

Comment: NotiStyle is a NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle and validateString is just check your string value is valid or not.

Comment: Can you please put those here too?