# Expand Firebase notification text on Android screen automatically

Tags: android, firebase

Notifications over 35 characters sent through Firebase are not displayed completely on the Android screen. For full display on Android screen, press the Expansion button (V).
What is the setting for full text display, without pressing the Expansion (V) button?
For better understanding of the scenario, attach images of the notification on the Android screen.

[image: current scenario]
[image: appropriate scenario]

**Manisfet**

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />

</application>
```

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Firebase. The Android system determines if it will show all text or if the user will have to expand it based on how many total notifications user has. With new Android OS, system will even "group" more than 5 notifications from the same app together. There is no way for any app to control that.

Comment: I get notifications from other applications, where the text is displayed in full, meaning without a push of a button to expand the text content.
I believe it's a script for a text expansion to be automatic when displayed on the Android notification bar

Comment: This is independent of Firebase and is an Android feature. [Is possible set Expanded Notification as default in Big Text Notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23331682)