# Multiple Lines of text message for Push Notification using FCM with Ionic 1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying for push notification with multiple lines text message. I have tried many changes like FCMService.java with setBigStyle text format, HTML.fromHTML, and some other. But not able to get the multiple line message.

I have gone through multiple sites and solution but not work. Marking it at duplicate or vote down, help me. I will up flag for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry Guys!. I have found the solution.

No need of doing any kind of modification in the any file like FCMService.java or any other custom messages for showing of multiple lines of Notification while using Push Notification V5.

Remove the field "style", from the object you are sending notification.

Automatically the Multiple lines of notification will be seen.

For more information, upvote the answer, ask your query. I will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Below is my notification payload. Here I don't have any style at

```
{
  "registration_ids" : ["XXXXXX"],
  "priority" : "high",
  "content-available": "0",
  "notification": {
    "title": "New Message",
    "body": "You have an Instruction received. Please contact your admin to process further and more queries“,
    "badge": "2",
    "sound" : "default"

  },
  "data" : {
    "message": "New Message",
    "body": "You have an Instruction received RM",
    "sound" : "default",
    "actionId": "123456",
    "badgeCount": "1",
    "instructionType": "History",
    "targetFunction": "actions",
    "notificationType": "pvm"
  }
}
```