# Notification keeps expanding state by default

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

Is it possible to keep expand state by default for `setCustomBigContentView`?
It gets collapsed by default when I use `setCustomBigContentView` method even the size lower than default notification height.

```
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), 
                          R.layout.notification_layout);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = builder
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setCustomBigContentView(contentView)
                .setOngoing(true);
```

Note: Some users blindly search for similar headline instead of understanding the code and situation. I feel sorry for them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is possible set Expanded Notification as default in Big Text Notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331682/is-possible-set-expanded-notification-as-default-in-big-text-notifications)