# How to expand custom notifications without user swipe?

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, expand

I have a custom notification that I want to be displayed in expanded view by default as sticky pop up that doesn't go away until interacted with - or expand without requiring a swipe down from the user. How would I be able to do this? I keep reading you can't do that because there's a limit by the OS but other apps like Daylio do this.

This is an example of the expanded notification visible by default.

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331682/is-possible-set-expanded-notification-as-default-in-big-text-notifications

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for, the notification example that I listed is in the expanded state even when it is displayed - not just in the notification center. I attached a new image for you to see