# Show Android Notification always expanded

Tags: android, notifications, exoplayer

I have created a exoplayer audio player with a notification to play pause audio.
Inside notification there is a small dropdown arrow to expand and collapse the notification (As shown in images attached) . Is it possible to remove those small arrows and make notification always expanded?

[image]
[image]

Regards,
Ali

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23331716/15298643

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, I think that you can use the media control that is introduced in Android 11, it's easy to set up and full of the features that you want. Find an introduction about it here in this [developer blog article](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/playing-nicely-with-media-controls.html).

You can also have a look into the [UAMP sample](https://github.com/android/uamp/blob/main/docs/FullGuide.md#notifying-the-user) to get more insight into how they handled the player notification using the `PlayerNotificationManager`.