# Notification with button that upon click take an action without opening activity

Tags: android

I am trying to create a notification where  I add button to it that would basically do some action. I know I can do the following

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(con)
            .setSmallIcon(image)
            .setContentTitle("title")
            .addAction(icon, title, intent)
```

My questions are:
1) Is adding button supported in API 5.0+ ONLY or also in 4.x? I read different answers about it

2) The action seems to be associated with opening an activity. Is there away I can have it so when you click on a button it takes an action without having to open the activity (Either through broadcast receiver or some other way)? As far as I know Intent opens activities.

Thank you so much

Comment: AFAIK Adding a button works with API > 11

Comment: you can see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249871/android-notification-buttons-not-showing-up] this

Comment: Yes you can do some action without open activity you can achieve it with using transparent Activity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It will work in Android 4.1 and later. [See official doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#addAction(int,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).
2. If  you want to do action with out any UI update(i.e., showing any activity), I suggest send a pending intent(which will trigger a broadcast receiver) as a parameter for notification action

i) Create a `BroadcastReceiver` named `MyBroadcastReceiver`
ii) Add your action in `BroadcastReceiver's` `onReceive` method
iii) Create a `PendingIntent`

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this,MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, mIntent , 0);
```

iv) Add it to Notification

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(con)
        .setSmallIcon(image)
        .setContentTitle("title")
        .addAction(icon, title, mPendingIntent)
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Is adding button supported in API 5.0+ ONLY or also in 4.x?

It will work in **Android 4.1 and later**. See [official doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#addAction(int,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).

> 2)...As far as I know Intent opens activities.

Yes, you can use BroadcastReceiver or Service for executing logic that doesn't involve UI. First of all, you can build intent to launch activity, broadcast receiver, or service. Secondly, the third argument of NoticiationCompat.Builder#addAction is *PendingIntent*, not an *Intent*. You can use [PendingIntent.getService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getService(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)) to create an PendingIntent for service, for instance.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getService(android.content.Context, int, android.content.Intent, int)